# Regex with Special character

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I want to search inside a Emailbody to the subject. I use

```
var msgHeader = (data.match(/Subject:\s*(.+)\s+To/i))[1];
```

But I have now a problem. Inside the Subject there is also a To so the header is cut unhappy.
I need to expand the string with ":" to "To:"
So I tried:

```
var msgHeader = (data.match(/Subject:\s*(.+)\s+To\\:/i))[1];
```

But this will throw a error. What is the secret to looks from "Subject:" up to "To:"?

Comment: Can you add some example data to the question?

Comment: @anuhava This I tried first, but cause also an error

Comment: Could you give to us an example of the data so we could give you an actual working snippet instead of asking you to test out

Comment: `/Subject:\s*([\s\S]*?)\s+To/i`, and check if there is a match before accessing `match[1]`.